# Testing the influence of Time Period on Y

Tags: regression

I am trying to measure the decay in the rate of sales from period one, to period two, to period three, to period four. My sample data structure looks like this:

```
Product Sales Period X1 X2 X3 
A       140    1     (omitted)
A       130    2
A       90     3
A       70     4
B       100    1
B       95     2
B       80     3
B       74     4
C       111    1
C       100    2
C       60     3
C       40     4
```

What I did, was estimating an OLS by regressing Sales on Period as a categorical variable (and a collection of other independent variables).

```
Period |        coeff       stdev        t      p-value   
          2  |  -.043726    .0155788    -2.81   0.005    -.0742619   -.0131901
          3  |  -.0212789   .0155709    -1.37   0.172    -.0517993    .0092415
          4  |  -.0156485   .0155811    -1.00   0.315    -.0461889    .0148918
```

However, I realized that this might not be a correct approach given that I essentially treat periods as simply independent values without accounting for the time component (1 goes before 2, 2 goes before 3, etc.).

Can you suggest another way of measuring this so-called "decay rate" based on a period?

Answer (score 1):

Fitting a trend line (or any polynomial in time) as you are doing (sales on period) is based upon a model assumption which should studiously avoided be voided UNLESS the residuals from such a model are free of any structure ( such as memory , pulses , level or trend shifts , or changes in error variance over time (period) ). Modern analysis suggests forming a possible hybrid model containing memory (ARIMA) and any needed dummy variables to account for pulses , level or trend shifts . Upon obtaining a model that can be statistically verified to be sufficient the next step is to somehow "label the model". The correct label might be a constant decay from period to period or a constant change from period to period or an auto-regressive dependency from period to period. Now the good news is all models developed in this way can be characterized as "weighted average of previous values" where the number of periods and the weights themselves (most likely unequal !) are presented.

Often time there may be too few observations to empirically form a unique model for each series. In this case some (professional) judgement may be needed to apply a common model form to all series .

Comment: Thank you! Your comments are very helpful, yet quite sophisticated and might require existing time series knowledge. Is it possible at all to measure this effect by using a simple linear regression?

Comment: You can use multiple linear regression where you pre-specify predictor series that are the lags of the output series ..Now if you don't know how many lags to include  (and which lags they are) you can specify a (LARGE) number of them and do a step-down to delete insignificant structure.. However all of this fails if you have pulses in the data or level shifts or trends or if you over-saturate you model or other reasons. Simple methods are often simply rong ! thus smart identification strategies are often (always !) useful  "smart software" can be a proxy for the "lack of time series knowledge"

Comment: On a side note, I found this Stata post here http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2008-10/msg00648.html. It looks strikingly similar to mine, except that I would actually estimate the average sales rate across all products for each consecutive day.

Comment: Well that's an "equine of a different hue"  or a  horse of a different color.. Daily data is rich in effects ( day effects , holiday effects , eek effects , month effects , particular day/week of the month effects et. al . These additional effects need to be identified/harvested . You might look at my many posts on daily data analysis to get up to speed , so to speak .